# Домен третьего уровня

Tags: nginx, linux, веб-программирование, сервер

Домен третьего уровня. (В системе уже есть домен второго уровня. Под ним хотелось бы создать поддомен.)

Comment: В связке Gentoo+Nginx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если для nginx, то так: [динамические поддомены с использованием nginx+apache](http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/webdev/101585/). Вот  [здесь](http://forum.antichat.ru/thread91035.html) описано для апача.